# Javascript cant increase value of select

Tags: javascript

So i am having some issues with increasing a Selects NAME="" value..

I am working on a loop where everytime it goes arround the value must end with a higher number...

the following lines which don't work are :

```
$('select[name="Ma_uurVan'+ xy + '"]').attr("name", "Ma_uurVan" + [y]);
            $('select[name="Ma_uurTot'+ xy + '"]').attr("name", "Ma_uurTot" + [y]);
```

Hope anyone of you could spot my mistake

html :

```
 <tr name="Ma_uren0">
    <td>
       <select name="Ma_uurVan0">
        <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
        <option value="08:30">08:30</option>
        <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
      </select>
   </td>
</tr>
```

javascript :

```
var i = 0;
    var x = 0;
    var y = 1;
    var xy = 1;
    // functie voor maandag
    $('[name=Ma_addRow]').click(function (){
        if(x < 1)
        {
            $('[name="Ma_uren0"]').clone().attr('name', 'Ma_uren'+[y]).insertAfter('[name="Ma_uren0"]');
            $('select[name="Ma_uurVan0"]').find('select').attr('name', 'Ma_uurVan' + [y] );
            $('select[name="Ma_uurTot0"]').attr('name', 'Ma_uurTot' + [y] );
            x++;
            y++;
        }else
        {
            $('[name="Ma_uren0"]').clone().attr('name', 'Ma_uren'+[y]).insertAfter('[name="Ma_uren'+[xy]+'"]');
            $('select[name="Ma_uurVan'+ xy + '"]').attr("name", "Ma_uurVan" + [y]);
            $('select[name="Ma_uurTot'+ xy + '"]').attr("name", "Ma_uurTot" + [y]);
            y++;
            xy++;
        }
    });
```

hope anyone could figure it out..

Comment: no, the ' are correct.. but what is `"Ma_uurVan" + [y]`, shouldn't that be `"Ma_uurVan[" + y + "]"` or sth? best make a jsfiddle with all the relevant HTML

Comment: okay i will try now hold on a few mins.

Comment: Nope wont change the number at the end...

Comment: please make a jsfiddle or provide all the relevant code

Comment: i just provided all relevant code mate.. and i cant check in jsfiddle if the name values goes as it needs to right?

Answer (score 1):

I think the mistake is because of you increase `xy` every time and you initialize the variable to 1.
So `$('select[name="Ma_uurVan'+ xy + '"]')` always return null.

Last, I think you use 3 variables while 2 should be enough since `y` is always equal to `xy`.

Comment: i know but its a bit more accessible for further actions so thats why we did this.